# as3 wait until image loaded on button click

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, event-handling, bulkloader

I have a slideshow that loads image files with the BulkLoader class from [here](https://github.com/arthur-debert/BulkLoader). When the first image is loaded completely, it gets added to a MovieClip container to add it to the stage.. and it gets displayed fullscreen, but only if a button is clicked:

```
fullScreenButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, showFull);

function showFull(e:MouseEvent):void {   
    stage.addChild(mcSlideHolder);
    ...
}
```

Loading the image with BulkLoader in a separate function loadAllSlides() that gets called right from the start:

```
imageLoader = new BulkLoader("imgLoader");
imageLoader.add(new URLRequest(paths[0]), {id:"slide_0});                                
imageLoader.get("slide_0).addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onFirstSlideLoaded);
imageLoader.start(1);
```

And during the loading process:

```
function onFirstSlideLoaded(e:Event):void
{
    firstImage = imageLoader.getBitmap(e.currentTarget.id);
    currentImage.addChild(firstImage);
    mcSlideHolder.addChild(currentImage); 
    mcSlideHolder.dispatchEvent(new Event("firstImgAdd"));
}
```

This works fine unless the fullScreenButton is clicked before the image is loaded completely, then of course nothing is visible. How do I get button click event that calls showFull() to wait until the image is loaded/added to the container or how can I add it again? What is a possible/the best approach?

I tried dispatching a custom event "firstImgAdd" that adds the image again to the container when the fullScreenButton is clicked, as well as with a try/catch block or even a simple if condition but none of them worked, meaning the image does not get added to the container after it has finished loading when the button is clicked too early.
Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance

Comment: Can you clarify: are you talking about actual fullScreen mode of the Flash Player? From the code you're showing, I can't imagine why you wouldn't go fullscreen on the button click, and then see the image appear (pop on) when it finished loading. Are you asking how to defer going fullScreen after the click? If so, you can't do that. Flash Player security restrictions require that the call to go fullscreen has a mouseEvent or keyboardEvent handler below it in the call stack.

Comment: yes, sure: yes it's about the actual fullScreen mode of Flash. I put the code for the adding of the mcSlideHolder now after calling the fullscreen mode with "stage.displayState = StageDisplayState.FULL_SCREEN;" but still no success. No, I don't want to defer going fullScreen, just wait for the image (which is being loaded in the background) to complete loading and add it to the stage to be visible

Answer (score 1):

Probably the best thing to do would be to make the button unavailable or disabled until the load is complete. Another option may be to cue the request if the load is not complete.

Something like:

```js
private var slideLoaded:Boolean = false;
private var requestCued:Boolean = false;

imageLoader = new BulkLoader("imgLoader");
imageLoader.add(new URLRequest(paths[0]), {id:"slide_0"});                                
imageLoader.get("slide_0").addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onFirstSlideLoaded);
imageLoader.start(1);

fullScreenButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, showFull);

function showFull(e:MouseEvent):void {   
    if (slideLoaded)
        stage.addChild(mcSlideHolder);
    else 
        requestCued = true;
}

function onFirstSlideLoaded(e:Event):void {
    slideLoaded = true;
    firstImage = imageLoader.getBitmap(e.currentTarget.id);
    currentImage.addChild(firstImage);
    mcSlideHolder.addChild(currentImage);
    if (requestCued)
        stage.addChild(mcSlideHolder);
}
```

Comment: disabling the button until the image is loaded is an option (and worked), but not my preferred one, considering user experience: depending on the users internet connection speed and the filesize it may take a while until the load is complete..it's probably better to enable the button and display some kind of waiting circle/animation until the image can be displayed..

Answer (score 0):

This is a security violation.
You can NOT instantiate full screen mode without user interaction.

The ONLY way to activate full screen is directly from user interaction period.IE:a mouse click
Look at it this way, any hacker trying to force a user to watch their ad full screen and not have a way out because the user shut full screen down the hacker could just reopen it.

The closest you can get to full screen without user interaction would be to expand the SWF to the full size of the HTML document.

Sorry to burst your bubble I have myself tried to hack around this also. An actual user click event has to be in the stack for you to be able to go full screen

Comment: no, that's not the problem..I know about the required user interaction before going fullscreen. I have the fullscreen mode activated only when the button is clicked, my problem is that the image is not visible, when the button to go fullscreen is clicked before the image is loaded completely.